# Refactoring code from map<char, T> to vector<T>

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, portability

Actually, the problem is in the title. I have a working code where I heavily use `std::map<char, T> table`. Profiler told me that `operator[]` method is quite time consuming. So I think since char has only a few different values (from -128 to 127 I suppose) it is possible to change type of my `table` variable to `std::vector<T>` or even `T[256]`.
My question is how to do it safely. I mean I cannot rely that `char` type has exactly 256 distinct values so I want to add some portable code that would use something like std::numeric_limits and will ensure that `table` size covers all possible values of `char`. And another problem that is that I didn't care about negative values while using `std::map`. But I cannot do the same with `std::vector` because `table[(char)-15]` will produce an exception. Does it mean that easiest solution is to cast all keys from `char` to `unsigned char` before calling `operator[]` of my `table`? If it doesn't, how should I do this?

Comment: You have already mentioned the solution: You have `std::numeric_limits<char>::max() - std::numeric_limits<char>::min()` possible values and for any `char c`, `c - std::numeric_limits<char>::min()` is in the index range.

Comment: @CoryKramer, No, I didn't. But efficiency is as important as portability for me. I will give it a shot, but I am pretty sure that `std::vector<T>` works faster in the case.

Comment: `char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte, and I've yet to see an architecture that doesn't have 8-bit bytes. It's pretty safe to assume `char` will always have 256 values.

Comment: @ElderBug I just googled and found that: http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/spru281f The C55x DSP has got 16 bits char.

Comment: @ElderBug Well, 30 years isn't that old, actually, compared with MIPS and ARM.

Comment: Have you considered API? For example `erase()` for a `std::vector` will shift all the not only shrink the vector's size, but also change the indices after everything after the erased element.

Comment: @user3528438 My bad for this one, I thought the chip was obsoleted. My point is just that worrying about exotic architecture will do more harm than good. There is also a lot of chips that use non-standard C, and no-one seems to care about them, even though they may be more common than those with 16-bit chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest introducing your own class to use, which would encapsulate `std::vector<T>` in some way and provide the interface you need.

If you're going to reuse a lot of `std::vector`'s interface, you may even consider using the implemented-in-terms-of relationship:

```
template <class T>
struct MyMap : protected std::vector<T>
{
  using std::vector::vector;
  using std::vector::push_back;
  // ...
  // List other members which you want to inherit verbatim

  T& operator[] (char idx)
  {
    return std::vector::operator[](idx - std::numeric_limits<char>::min());
  }
  // Re-implement the members which you need to
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest switching to a [`std::unordered_map<char, T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)
.

For `std::unordered_map` the complexity of [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) is stated as approximatley `O(1)`

> Average case: **constant**, worst case: linear in size.

For `std::map` the complexity of [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) is `O(logN)`

> **Logarithmic** in the size of the container.

Comment: Could be, but need to be benchmarked: with a limited number of keys, hashing them may be more expensive than searching them. Still switching to `unordered_map` should be immediate and painless, so worth a try.

Comment: `O(1)` doesn't mean it's better. `unordered_map[]` involve hashing and bucket management, while `map[]` is just a tree search.

Comment: Those are both good points, there is overhead in using an unordered_map (bucket allocation, management, etc) and a map (tree balancing, etc). I agree the best thing to do would be profile the code using both containers and see if the switch is warranted. If both are poorly performant, then a `std::array` with some additional key checking is probably another way to go.